# html5 datetime-local control - how to hide seconds?

Tags: css, html

With the following Control:

**Note I set the value per:**
 http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="transaction_date" value="2011-05-31T10:07:41">
```

**Note the below link does not render seconds?**

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_datetime-local

Is it possible to configure it to not allow seconds to be editable, i.e. just not display the seconds in the control?

**EDIT**

The below image is rendered using chrome? Why do I get the seconds available here but the w3school link above does not have seconds? How do I get chrome to not render the seconds?

[image: rendered in chrome]

Comment: What is you actual HTML code? I’m pretty sure it contains a `value` attribute.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I updated the above to show the actual value I am using and the reference to the spec that defines the datetime format.

Comment: Now we are getting at something. The problem is simply that you are setting an invalid value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The seconds are by default not settable, on browsers that implement the control as defined in W3C [HTML5 CR](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#local-date-and-time-state-%28type=datetime-local%29). The reason is that the granularity is set, in seconds, by the `step` attribute, which has the default value of 60. This is how it works in Chrome, Opera, and Safari.

If you actually wanted to allow seconds to be specified, you would set `step=1`.

On browsers that do not support this input type, the control degrades to a text input control, where any data can be entered by the user and the data is not processed in any way by the browser (specifically, not checked for being a date and time at all).

**Update** to address the modified question: If the element has a `value` attribute that does not satisfy the requirements set by other attributes (including the default value of `step`), then the input initially suffers from a step mismatch. HTML5 CR says: “When the element is suffering from a step mismatch, the user agent may round the element's value to the nearest local date and time for which the element would not suffer from a step mismatch.” Opera follows this, Chrome does not. The morale is: don’t do that. Do not use a `value` attribute with a seconds part if you don’t want seconds.

Comment: Chrome is by default rendering seconds for me. See above screenshot. Would like to see an example using Chrome where seconds are not editable.

Comment: If Chrome renders seconds for you, then the reason is probably that you have a `value` attribute that specifies an initial value that does not meet the requirements. This is a bug, but to avoid it, don’t use such values.

Answer (score 2):

If I set the value of a `datetime-local` input with a string that omits the seconds, the `datetime-local` input omits the seconds.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2020-01-01T11:00" id="birthdaytime" />
```

And here's my output:

[image: datetime-local without seconds]

It also omits the seconds if I set the time to `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm` using JavaScript:

```
const pad = (i) => i < 10 ? `0${i}` : i;
const time = new Date(strTimeLocal); // ensure date object
const timeString = `${time.getFullYear()}-${pad(time.getMonth() + 1)}-${pad(time.getDate())}T${pad(time.getHours())}:${pad(time.getMinutes())}`;
$(selector)[0].value = timeString;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [W3C working draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime-local.html) doesn't specify any method of doing this, no.

However, as far as I am aware `datetime-local` is currently only supported by chrome and opera, and both implementations don't allow the user to modify the seconds.

Comment: See above EDIT to question.

Comment: By "modify the seconds" do you mean remove/add to the control or change the seconds value? I am definitely able to change the seconds value in Chrome.